# How to detect a selection on JavaFX TableView when clicking a highlighted item?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I need a way to get the user selection every time a user selects an item on a TableView, even if the item is already selected.

The `tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener` works when the user selects a *different* item from the one highlighted, but if the user selects the highlighted item again, it doesn't seem to work.

How would this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this:

```
tableView.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
        if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
            System.out.println(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
```

the code above doesn't work if you select the highlighted item again using editable table cell

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the clicks on the rows, use a custom `rowFactory`:

```
TableView<Item> table = ...
EventHandler<MouseEvent> clickListener = evt -> {
    TableRow<Item> row = (TableRow<Item>) evt.getTarget();
    if (!row.isEmpty()) {
        // do something for non-empty rows
        System.out.println("you clicked " + row.getItem());
    }
};

table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();

    // add click listener to row
    row.setOnMouseClicked(clickListener);

    return row;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way what i know:

```
 yourTableView.setOnMousePressed(e ->{
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && e.isPrimaryButtonDown() ){
                    int index = yourTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                    System.out.println("" + index);
                }
            });
```

put it in to constructor or initialize method in your corntroller class... :)